# Is there a problem with Pipes in Python multiprocessing on macOS?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm encountering some strange behavior with `Pipe` in Python multiprocessing on my Mac (Intel, Monterey). I've tried the following code in 3.7 and 3.11 and in both cases, not all the tasks are executed.

```
def _mp_job(nth, child):
    print("Nth is", nth)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from multiprocessing import Pool, Pipe, set_start_method, log_to_stderr
    import logging, time

    set_start_method("spawn")
    logger = log_to_stderr()

    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    with Pool(processes = 10) as mp_pool:

        jobs = []
        for i in range(20):
            parent, child = Pipe()
            # child = None
            r = mp_pool.apply_async(_mp_job, args = (i, child))
            jobs.append(r)

        while jobs:
            new_jobs = []
            for job in jobs:
                if not job.ready():
                    new_jobs.append(job)
            jobs = new_jobs
            print("%d jobs remaining" % len(jobs))
            time.sleep(1)
```

I know exactly what's going on, but I don't know why.

[**EDITED**: my explanation for what was happening was quite unclear on my first pass, as reflected in the comments, so I've cleaned it up. Thanks for your patience.]

If I run this code on my macOS Monterey machine, it will loop forever, reporting that some number of jobs are remaining. The logging information reveals that the child processes are failing; you'll see a number of lines like this:

```
[DEBUG/SpawnPoolWorker-10] worker got EOFError or OSError -- exiting
```

What's happening is that when the child worker dequeues a job and tries to unpickle the argument list, it encounters `ConnectionRefusedError` when unpickling the child connection side of the `Pipe` in the arguments (I know these details not because of the output of the function above, but because I inserted a traceback printout at the point in the Python multiprocessing library where the worker reports encountering the `OSError`). At that point the worker fails, having removed the job from the work queue but not having completed it. That's why I have `# child = None` in there; if I uncomment that, everything works fine.

My first suspicion is that this is a bug in Python on macOS (I haven't tested this on other platforms, but it makes no sense to me that something this basic would have been missed unless it's a platform-specific error). I don't understand why the child process would get `ConnectionRefusedError`, since the `Pipe` establishes a socket pair and you shouldn't be able to get `ConnectionRefusedError` in that case, as far as I understand.

This seems more likely to happen the more processes I have in the pool. If I have 2, it seems to work reliably. But 4 or more seem to cause a problem; I have a six-core computer, so I don't think that's part of what's happening.

Does anyone have any insight into this? Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback?  I'm not sure it's the Pipe that's causing the issue, but perhaps something you're sending over it.

Comment: Searching the entire CPython code base for "ConnectionRefused" gives 0 hits, and I can't reproduce the error you report when I run this code. Please show the full, exact error message, including complete stack trace.

Comment: My guess would be that since you're not saving a reference to `child` in the master process, the underlying socket gets cleaned up before the pool worker can open it.

Comment: (After further searching, I've determined that you probably meant `ConnectionRefusedError` instead of `ConnectionRefused`. It might seem unimportant, but using the actual exception name would have made it easier to help you.)

Comment: @Max Thanks for your comment. I know it's not anything I'm sending through the pipe, because, as you see in the code, I'm not actually sending anything through the pipe. Just passing the child connection to the worker occasionally causes the worker to fail.

Comment: @user2357112 My apologies for the lack of clarity. I've edited the description of the problem.

Comment: @user2357112 The problem is not a lack of reference to the `child` in the parent process. If I save the connection pairs in a global list outside the loop, the same thing happens.

Comment: I should also note that the number of jobs which are "stranded" is exactly the number of workers which report encountering an `OSError`.